# ¿Como puedo "subir" multimedia a mi .exe con PyInstaller?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Hice una pequeña interfaz grafica en tkinter de python 3.

la cosa resulta al pasar
de **archivo.py a archivo.exe**. pyinstaller no me trae las imágenes ni video, quiero decir si se encuentra en la ruta que especifique en el archivo si me las carga pero quisiera que fuera solo 1 archivo.exe que contenga ya las imágenes y el video que puse, sin necesidad de tener que buscarlos en una ruta, aun así dejo el código de lo que hice por si fuera necesario.

```
import tkinter as tk,threading
import imageio
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import pygame.mixer
import time
from tkinter import messagebox

#cargar video
video = imageio.get_reader("res\\3fish.mp4")

#Capturar frames y mostrarlas simulando un video
def stream(label):
    loops = 999
    for i in range (0,loops):
        for image in video.iter_data():
            frame_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(image))
            label.config(image=frame_image)
            label.image = frame_image
            time.sleep(0.01)

def subirVolumen():
    print("subir volumen")
    volumen = pygame.mixer.music.get_volume()
    volumen = volumen +0.01
    pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(volumen)

def bajarVolumen():
    print("bajar volumen")
    volumen = pygame.mixer.music.get_volume()
    volumen = volumen -0.01
    pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(volumen)

def presionarGuion():
    tk.messagebox.showinfo(title = "@cucharacha 2021", message = "Creado por cucharacha ( ´ ▽ ` )ﾉ")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #Iniciar
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("480x360")
    root.resizable(False,False)
    root.title("3fish")
    root.iconbitmap("res\\miniatura.ico")

    #Video 3fish
    my_label = tk.Label(root)
    my_label.place(x=-80,y=0)
    thread = threading.Thread(target=stream, args=(my_label,))
    thread.daemon = 1
    thread.start()

    #Musica
    pygame.mixer.init()
    pygame.mixer.music.load("res\\3fish.wav")
    pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(0.2)
    pygame.mixer.music.play(-1) #loop

    #Botones
    textura_guion = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("res\\guion.png"))
    boton_guion = tk.Button(root, image = textura_guion, command = presionarGuion)
    boton_guion.place(x=8, y=8,width= 34, height= 34)

    textura_T_ARRIBA = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("res\\T_ARRIBA.png"))
    boton_arriba = tk.Button(root, image = textura_T_ARRIBA, command = subirVolumen)
    boton_arriba.place(x=442, y=8,width= 36, height= 35)

    textura_T_ABAJO = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("res\\T_ABAJO.png"))
    boton_abajo = tk.Button(root, image = textura_T_ABAJO, command = bajarVolumen)
    boton_abajo.place(x=404, y=8,width= 36, height= 35)

    textura_SO_LONG = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("res\\so_long.png"))
    boton_so_long = tk.Button(root, image = textura_SO_LONG)
    boton_so_long.place(x=42, y=8,width= 362, height= 35)

    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Python no es un lenguaje compilado y aun en los lenguajes que si lo son, lo que quieres hacer es imposible. Existe la posibilidad de embeber archivos en los scripts con base64, pero no lo recomiendo para archivos de video.

Cuando PyInstaller "convierte" tu proyecto en un solo archivo .exe, lo que en realidad hace es crear en él tanto el interprete como los scripts y al ejecutarlo debe crear archivos temporales de todo ello antes de poder lanzar la aplicación. De echo si creas el .exe sin la opción `/F` (opción de un solo archivo) notarás como tu programa se ejecuta mucho más rápido debido a que no tiene que realizar esa operación.

Normalmente un programa siempre está estructurado en carpetas, sobre todo si utiliza archivos multimedia de grandes dimensiones como videos y es perfectamente normal que un programa dependa de varios archivos para su funcionamiento. Te invito a buscar un solo programa en tu carpeta %programfiles% que esté compuesto por un solo ejecutable y de paso puedes aprovechar para ver como suelen estar compuestas las estructuras de las carpetas de un programa.

Si a pesar de todo lo que te he explicado quieres hacerlo, puedes intentarlo con base64.